# How can I find out what software I've bought in the App Store?

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore, apple-id

I'm Using my iPhone 3G and haven't backup it as frequently as I should and would like to know what software I've bought for it. So I know I don't have to pay for it again. Yes I can try and buy the software but I want to know of all the apps I've bought.

I know some apps wont be available for my old iPhone but they will work if I buy a new one. I need to know how much money I will lose in Apps I can't use anymore. If I buy a new phone that isn't an iPhone.

So How can I find out what Apps I've bought for my iPhone. 
I have both Windows and Mac computers available.

The mac computer runs Mac os X 10.6.8, the iPhone 3G runs iOS 4.1.2

Answer (score 3):

### On iPhone

1. Open the App Store on your device.
2. Make sure you are signed in  the same Apple ID used for the original purchase.
3. Tap Updates from the bottom navigation bar.

[image]

4. Tap on Purchased on navigation bar

[image]

5. Tap Purchased on the resulting screen.
6. Locate the app in your Purchased tab. Tap the download button.

[image]

### On iTunes 11

1. Open iTunes on your computer.
2. Make sure that you have `Show iTunes in the Cloud
   Purchases` enabled in your iTunes preferences by going to iTunes >
   Preferences under the Store tab. Then, click OK.
3. If you're already signed in, choose Store > Sign In, and enter your Apple ID
   and password.
4. After you've signed in, click the <kbd>Library</kbd> located in the upper-right of the iTunes Store. Navigate to your iTunes library for the respective content type you wish to using the content selector in the upper-left. Choose Apps to download apps. Locate the item or title you wish to download. Click the download icon to download that item. For instance, you will want yours to say `Apps`.

[image: Yours will say Apps.]

**Note:** The download icon for previously purchased movies is located to the right of the movie title. To download previously purchased apps and books, you'll need to navigate to the Purchased page under the Quick Links section in the iTunes Store.

Comment: I followed your guide on iTunes 11, but that only shows the apps I've downloaded on this computer. I don't have an iCloud account. the amount of apps there is a total of 14. I've had my iPhone since late 2008 and I've downloaded far more than 14 apps. So this answer doesn't work.

Comment: Are you logged into the same account that you bought the apps with on your iPhone 3G?

Comment: Yes of course...